# C++ get current file name and use it on WinExec

Tags: c++

How can i get current file name without path, i want to use it on WinExec,

example for what am trying to do,

```
 WinExec("Do something to <mycurrentfilename.exe>", SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: Using argv[0] or GetModuleFileName() are two ways to get the filename to the currenly running executable in windows.

Comment: Why you do you need to remove the path?  Do you need to replace it with a different path?  `WinExec()` works with fully qualifies paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In common case you have to use [GetModuleFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Example:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sstream>

int main(void) {

    char myexepath[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    DWORD returnCode = GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, myexepath, MAX_PATH);
    if (returnCode != 0 && returnCode < MAX_PATH)
    {
        std::string filepath(myexepath);
        filepath = filepath.substr(filepath.find_last_of('\\') + 1);
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << "Do something to \"" << filepath << "\"";

        WinExec(ss.str().c_str(), SW_HIDE);
    }
    else
    {
        // process GetModuleFileName error.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example uses `char` encoding for filename, but it can be changed to `wchar_t` or universal `TCHAR`

Comment: Hello, it is possible to get only file.exe? without full path?

Comment: You need to parse the full filename manually to get the short filename, or use some kind of libraries, or `std::filesystem` since c++17. I edited post to show this.

Comment: The Win32 API has [`PathFindFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773589.aspx) and [`PathStripPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773756.aspx) functions: `std::string filepath = PathFindFileName(myexepath);` or `PathStripPath(myexepath); std::string filepath = myexepath;`